# Firebase and intranet

Tags: firebase

I'm not sure if this was answered somewhere in the documentation, but looking at the pricing tells me that Firebase has to work with client connected to the Internet at all times.

I am currently developing an application with Java-backed server and with client side done in GWT (Javascript). The application is meant to be deployed for "corporate" clients - that means in intranets.

Will Firebase be operational in these circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess I should have read into [FAQ](https://www.firebase.com/docs/faq.html) more thoroughly:

> **Can I run Firebase on my own servers?**
>   Firebase is a hosted cloud service, so the general answer is “no.” Some customers have very specific needs for where their sensitive data is physically stored and managed, so we may make exceptions. Contact us for more info.

Comment: If the intranet has access out to the internet then you should be fine. I ran some tests earlier today on our corporate intranet no problems at all.

Comment: @MikePugh do you mind how did you manage making authDomain localhost `authDomain: 'https://yourapp.firebaseio.com/'`. I couldn't read any bit because of domain restriction.